# Fantasy Novel, Girl on an Other-worldly Quest

Tags: story-identification, books

I can remember almost everything about this book except its title. It's about a girl living in a drought and she picks up this stopwatch (i think) that transports her to another world. She meets a purple furry creature that becomes her friend, a baby dragon, and this other strange creature who's been following her trying to protect her. She learns there is a war (or something) going on and someone is trying to destroy the Earth with a device planted at the earth's core. She has to collect a certain number of rods (or gems or something) from different worlds. One of the worlds is underwater and another one of fire. The only other detail I remember is the magic golden dust that heals and that at the end of the book she wishes for her furry friend to be resurrected. Hope someone recognizes it. Thanks!

Comment: Do you remember when you read this?